# C++ string data() function make references and pointers invalidated?

Tags: c++, stl

I am now reading 《The C++ Standard Library》.When I read the chapter of strings,I get a problem.
It tell us that if the contents are exported by data(),references and pointers that refer to the character of a string my be invalidated.

[image]

AS we know,data() returns the contents of the string as an array of characters and the return type is not a valid C-string because no '\0' character gets appended.

But why data() makes references and pointers invalidated?

Could someone interpret for me?Thanks a lot!

Comment: IIRC `data` in C++11 does include a `'\0'` as the buffer itself is required to contain one.

Comment: But 《The C++ StandardLibrary》 is published before C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `data` itself doesn't, calling mutable methods (non-`const`) afterward might invalidate the previous pointer. That's because when you modify the string, the inner char array might get changed or re-allocated.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 there was no requirement that the internal string representation had to be a contiguous buffer. It was also allowed to share the internals with another string (using reference counting, for example).

Therefore, a call to `data()` or `c_str()` might force the string to restructure its internal data, to be able to return a pointer to a char buffer.

Answer (score 0):

An example, assuming C++11 (so that `data()` is guaranteed to be null-terminated):

```
string s = "abc" ;
const char* p = s.data() ;
cout << p << endl ;
s = "ABCDE" ;
cout << p << endl ;
```

The second assignment to `s` invalidates `p`, because `s` might (here, it probably will) reallocate its internal buffer. So the result of the final `cout` is undefined. It might print "abc" or "ABCDE", or it might squirt cider in your ear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading a last C++11 draft and can't find anything that would support such claims:

> 21.4.1 pt 6: References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that basic_string object:
>
> — as an argument to any standard library function taking a reference to non-const basic_string as an argument.
>
> — Calling non-const member functions, except operator[], at, front, back, begin, rbegin, end, and rend.

And a footnote to first point:

> For example, as an argument to non-member functions swap() (21.4.8.8), operator>>() (21.4.8.9), and getline() (21.4.8.9), or as an argument to basic_string::swap()

`data()` member function is declared `const`, so it should not invalidate anything.

Comment: @Downvoter - how about some explanation, what's wrong with my answer?